# SQL: Remove two rows and insert a new row into table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to replace row pairs (row with name="aaa" appear first and row with name="bbb" appear later, both rows have same id) by a new row with the same id but name="ccc".

Original table:

```
timestamp(primary key)        id     name 
2020-02-20...                 1      aaa
2020-02-20...                 1      aaa  -----> first row
2020-02-20...                 1      ddd
2020-02-20...                 1      bbb  -----> second row
2020-02-20...                 2      aaa
2020-02-20...                 2      ccc
2020-02-20...                 2      ddd
```

New table:

```
timestamp(primary key)        id     name 
2020-02-20...                 1      aaa
2020-02-20...                 1      aaa
2020-02-20...                 1      ccc  -----> replaced by this row
2020-02-20...                 1      ddd
2020-02-20...                 2      aaa
2020-02-20...                 2      ccc
2020-02-20...                 2      ddd
```

timestamp is the primary key and it is increasing.

Is it possible to achieve this in PostgresSQL?

Comment: SQL tables represent UNORDERED sets.  There is no "second row" without a column that specifies the ordering.  What if the rows are in a different order?

Comment: I have issue with understanding. For me id is key, so must be unique. Can you please elaborate more on what you are trying to do?

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Sorry for the bad example. I just updated it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this should do what you want:

```
(select id, name
 from t
 where name not in ('aaa', 'bbb') or
       name = 'aaa' and not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.name = 'bbb')  or
       name = 'bbb' and not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.name = 'aaa')           
) union all
(select id, 'ccc'
 from t
 where name in ('aaa', 'bbb')
 group by id
 having count(*) = 2
)
```